# Cannot find where to assign users to territory

Tags: territory-management

I have created a test territory and want to assign a user to it now. In the Salesforce guide it says I should go to the Territory detail page and add a user to the related list. I cannot find this. Where can I find the territory detail page? When I look at the territory page layout, there seems to be no User related list or Manage User button.
Tia.

Comment: Never used Territories yet .... But verifiy this one --- Setup->Territories ->User Territory Associations->Fields ---- Do you find "User" lookup here ?

Answer (score 1):

First goto --**setup** --> left quick search type **Territory** --> Click on **Territory Models** click on `Territory Models`

You can see all the Territory Models --> Now click on **View rule** link

Now you can see all the rules,

[image]

Now if you click on Rule name you can see **Assigned Territories**

Click on **Assigned Territories**

Here you can see the user assign to territory

[image]

Comment: Hello, for some reason my assigned territories list is empty. Really strange because I click on view rules next to my territory, so I would think it is assigned to it?

Comment: first you need to create territory.

Comment: click on setup-->Territory Models--> there you can see all the Territory Models   now click on  View Hierarchy- Click territory

Comment: @Lily you able to create territory?